# Direct3D 11 Access is Denied

Tags: c++, direct3d11

I am trying to create a 3D simulation, the code is  [here](https://pastebin.com/GBv4gssT) and the vertex shader is [here](https://pastebin.com/K3AFzahT), as you can imagine the pixel shader is just a straight forward function which passes the input straight to output, please forgive the lack of comments and sanity, I'm new to D3D.

Well basically the problem is that it runs fine on my PC, but on my laptop all I get is "Access is Denied". Which is a problem since I need to make the sim portable. My laptop has DirectX 12 installed and has directdraw and direct3d acceleration enabled. It's an AMD Readeon Graphics Processor chip type and its name is AMD Radeon vega 3 graphics. The laptop is brand new so I don't expect that I need to update drivers (please correct me if I am wrong).

```
enter code here
```

In addition in its early stages, the program managed to run a cube, but since I made a very rudimental object importer, that's where the problem started..

Comment: Where does this error message come from?

Comment: If i run it from command line it is returned there, otherwise it produces a MessageBox but then disappears almost immediately so i can't read it. If I keep trying it, eventually the file seems to delete itself and then the messagebox stays and says it cannot find the file..

Comment: Since the file deletes itself, is it possible that your virus scanner thinks it's a virus?

Comment: I guess at this point I can't rule that kind of thing out.. Although I don't have any additional security software installed other than Windows Defender.. Like I said, the exact same program ran before with a cube, the only difference is that it now reads an OBJ file, which is also a function I previously tested without any problems.

Comment: As it turns out, McAfee was pre installed with a trial version, and it kept deleting the file without giving me any indication. You can write this as a response if you like, and I will flag it as the answer :D